# in Pinescript, Alert When Diversions With Lower 'close' Price Than Previous Diversions Appears

Tags: pine-script

Indicators in Trading View : Divergence for any indicators v4

Before I write it, I'm a beginner.

Existing alert:

```
// When "Positive Diversity" appears, it's an alert
Alert condition (pos_reg_div_detected, title='Positive Regular Division Deted', message='Positive Regular Divergence Detected')
```

Allert you want:

```
// The alert that occurs when the current diversion is lower in closing price than the previous diversion
This is what I've tried.
Alertcondition (pos_reg_div_detected[1] > pos_reg_div_detected)
```

As expected, it's an error.

I'm very new to it. Your help would be greatly appreciated.

`if pos_reg_div_detected[1] > pos_reg_div_detected`